# Magento duplicate Content due to Store Code in URL

Tags: magento, seo, duplicates

I have **domain.org/uk/test.html** and **domain.org/us/test.html** - both have the same content. Rel canonical doesn't help, due to the fact that i want all /uk pages to be indexed in United Kingdom and all /us pages to be indexed in US and A. How to solve this problem, so that google does not see duplicate content but indexes the pages according to the country?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: HTML is for sure no "programming language"! But than there shall never ever be HTML questions. The question is not even magento related!

Answer (score 0):

ahreflang tag in the  will help and it will tell Google each page for which country it refers.

Comment: If you can't change the content, you have to do all the other optimizations stuff for the multilingual website by adding the below:
1 - ahreflang
2 - XMlsite map with alternate tag for countries and languages

Hope this will help, but as i told you the most important thing is the content.

Also try to change the page title at least, this could help.

Answer (score 0):

Nadeem brought me into the right direction its all about **hreflang** https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/12504/how-to-add-hreflang-tags-or-other-meta-tags-to-pages-in-magento